# Passing CharArray to Method

Tags: java, arrays, char

I'm trying to pass my char array grid1 to the method called status. I'm receiving the error char cannot be converted to char[][]. How would I pass grid1 so it would work in the for loop?

```
    for (int row = 0; row < 30; row++){
        for (int col = 0; col < 30; col ++){
            if (status(grid1[row][col], row, col)){

            }
        }
    }



    public boolean status(char [][] grid, int a, int b){

    char value = grid[a][b];    
        if (value == 'X'){
            //add X to another array
            return true;
        } else {
        return false;
        }
        //add - to another array
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem is that your method signature is expecting an array and you call it using a value from the array.

call like:

```
 status(grid1, row, col)
```

or fix the method signature

```
public boolean status(char grid){

    char value = grid;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just replace

```
if (status(grid1[row][col], row, col)){
```

with

```
if (status(grid1, row, col)){
```

Answer (score 0):

`grid1[row][col]` is a single element of `char` array, therefore is of type `char`. You need to pass the whole array `grid1`.

Answer (score 0):

You're already dereferencing your grid1 array in the loop. So unless that loop is to be part of your status method for whatever reason, your status method could be a lot simpler: you don't need to pass a `char[][]`, you could pass a `char`. And clearly you don't need the column and row indexes. Your method should be like this:

```
public boolean status(char value){

        if (value == 'X'){
            //add X to another array
            return true;
        } else {
        return false;
        }
        //add - to another array
}
```